# How to compute the number of edges to change to make the undirected graph a single component?

Tags: python, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

I was trying to solve this problem with the following code. But the answers aren't accurate for all inputs.

**Problem   Statement**

There   are  N  cities  and  N  one-way bridges in  Byteland.   There   is  exactly one incoming    and one outgoing
bridge  for each    city.
Byteland    wants   to  be  "elligible" to  host    the World   Cup.    A   country is  "elligible" for the World
Cup,    if  and only    if  you can travel  from    any city    to  any other   city    of  that    country.    You are asked   to  perform
the minimum number  of  steps   to  help    Byteland    become  an  elligible   World   Cup host.
For each    step    you can swap    the destinations    of  two bridges.

For example:    We  have    two bridges  A -> B     and 
C -> D  (there  is  a   bridge  from     A  to   B  and from     C  to   D ).   If  we  swap    their   destinations,   we  will    have    two
bridges  A -> D     and  C -> B .

**Input Format**

First   line    contains    one integer,     T  denoting    the number  of  test    cases.
For each    test    there   will    be  two lines:
    First   line    contains    one integer,     N.
    Second  line    contains     N  integers,   where   the  X th   integer denotes city    where   bridge  goes    from    city     X .

**Output Format**

Just print the answer to the problem, one line per case.

**Sample Input**

```
2
4
3 1 2 4
3
2 3 1
```

**Sample Output**

```
1
0
```

**My Code**

```
for i in range(input()):
    n = input()
    bridges = {}
    connection = [int(y) for y in raw_input().split(' ')]
    for j in range(n):
        bridges[j+1] = connection[j]
    #print bridges
    count = 0
    swapped = True
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        if swapped:
            swapped = False
            for j in range(1, n+1):
                if bridges[bridges[j]] == j:
                    bridges[j], bridges[1 if (j+1)%n == 0 else (j+1)%n] = bridges[1 if (j+1)%n == 0 else (j+1)%n], bridges[j]
                    swapped = True
                    #print bridges
                    count += 1
    print count
```

Comment: There is no help in the comment section of hackerrank?

Comment: It looks like a graph algorithm question.

Comment: The first sample input, is buggy. It says `4` is connected to `4`

Comment: Yes, I've added the Graph tag to this question now.

Comment: 4 is connected to 4 through a self-loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89456/discussion-between-amirouche-and-somnath-rakshit).

Answer (score 2):

You have to compute the connected components, then the number of swap is equal to the number of components minus one.

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    N = int(input())
    bridges = {index + 1: int(connection) for index, connection in enumerate(input().split())}
    visited = set()
    component_count = 0
    towns = list(bridges.keys())
    while towns:
        current = towns[0]
        component = set()
        while current not in visited:
            towns.remove(current)
            visited.add(current)
            current = bridges[current]

        component_count += 1

    print(component_count - 1)
```

The code does the following:

- start at the first town not visited yet (outer loop), and visit as much town as possible followinng the bridges connections (inner loop)
- each time the inner loop breaks, it means that we met a town we already met which makes a component in the graph.
- Break the loop and increment the number of component. Start again with a new twon that is not visited

This gives the correct result because we are guaranteed that components are cycles, you can break the cycle (swap a connection) to connect a component to another without breaking the component.